# Build a plot with data from three different areas to observe trends

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm working on trace element concentrations in rivers inside a catchment area. I'm always looking at the same two elements, cadmium (Element 1) and aluminium (Element 2).

I have three different rivers, with fluctuating concentrations, found at the same date (3 different teams on each river).

My aim would be to have a chart where the three rivers appear, but where rivers are ranked according to the concentrations found (where we could see which river contributes the most i.e. which river is the most impacted).

Any thoughts on how I could proceed? I'm using excel, but can jump on R if needed.

[image]

Comment: It's not 100% clear what it is you want. Can you maybe provide a very basic set of data and the corresponding chart?

Comment: I've provided a screenshot of the data above. As for the chart, I'm having difficulties providing something clear

Comment: Have you tried putting all the datain one table? That would be the first step, I would think

Comment: I've put everything in one table yes

Comment: And? Why don't you [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1732883/edit) to show us that table and the chart you can generate from it, then explain exactly how that differs from the result you want.

Comment: @user156 ,, my suggestions ,, either you make 3 different graph for 3 Rivers,,,, since combing data needs records to FILTER as per River, TIME SPAN & Points !!

Comment: Create the Pivot Chart for each river, you can use the Slicer to filter.

Comment: What do you plan to plot in this chart? Concentration on y axis vs date on X axis? If you do that, the river with the highest concentration will stand out already. I am not sure what you mean when you say you want to rank the rivers? Do you not want to plot the actual concentration but simply show which river is rank 1,2,3 at each point in time?

Comment: Then there is the question of the different points on the rivers - should they all be plotted separately? Or averaged? Or find the maximumn conc for each river? 
Plotting multiple series from separate tables is easy as long as they have the same "shape", you just chart one then add the other series to it (you can even do this with copy/paste but sometimes it is clearer to do this through the chart data dialog box).